# In NodeJS bot implementation why use onTurnError vs own try/catch?

Tags: botframework

in a NodeJS bot implementation, I see there is a onTurnError property on BotFrameworkAdapter.  The doc doesn't say much about it.  When would I use that property vs. my own try/catch?

For example:

```
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter();
adapter.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {
 // handle the error
};
```

vs

```
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter();
adapter.processActivity(req, res, async(turnContext) => {
 try {
 // process the turn
 } catch (error) {
 //handle the error
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question and it got me curious, so I did some testing. As far as I can tell, there isn't a difference. After some additional digging, [you can see here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/2115012394877abcfc8234ebad43d09b9ac2d9d0/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/botAdapter.ts#L59) that `botAdapter.onTurnError` doesn't do anything more than just catch the error.

However, if you want to do some complex error handling, this provides a handler for you so you don't have to write your own and instead of doing something like:

```
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        try {
            await myBot.onTurn(context);
        } catch (error) {
            myErrorHandler(error);
        }
    });
});

const myErrorHandler = (error) => {
    // Many lines of complex error handling code
}
```

You would just do:

```
adapter.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {
    // Many lines of complex error handling code
};

server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        await myBot.onTurn(context);
    });
});
```

It's just a little cleaner.